# perform more than one operation on MERGE ... THEN in SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server, merge

I am using `MERGE` to perform `UPSERT` something. However in the `THEN` section I need to perform more than one operation, I need to both `INSERT` to table and also `UPDATE` something in another table. 
My problem is that I don't seem to see how to perform more than one action.

I tried this:

```
MERGE tblCategories AS T
    USING @RELEVANT_CATS AS S
    ON (T.CatId = S.CatId)
    WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET
        THEN
            BEGIN 
                INSERT (BizID, RequestId) VALUES(S.CatId, @CatId);
            END
```

The `BEGIN` and `END` are not allowed here for some reason.

Also tried this:

```
MERGE tblCategories AS T
    USING @RELEVANT_CATS AS S
    ON (T.CatId = S.CatId)
    WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET
        THEN EXECUTE INSERT_CAT S.CatId, @CatId;
```

Where `INSERT_CAT` is some stored procedure that performs what I need, but again, this syntax is not allowed.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start a transaction.
Add the [`output` clause](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Bb510625%28v=SQL.120%29.aspx) to your merge and capture the results of the merge into a table variable.
Use the table variable to update the other table where the captured `$action` was `'INSERT'`.
Commit the transaction.

Comment: Wonderful! Thank you.